# Do I need to create a new runner for each tag in Cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber

I have groups of test cases in Cucumber (I use: Cucumber + Junit).
Structure:

```
GRP_1 User login
  Test1_Userlogin.feature
  Test2_Userlogin.feature
  Test3_Userlogin.feature
GRP_2 Registration
  Test1_Registration.feature
  Test2_Registration.feature
GRP_3 Shipping
  Test1_Shipping.feature
GRP_4 UserPanel
  Test1_UserPanel.feature
  ...
```

For each group I have Runner class:
GRP_1_Runner,   GRP_2_Runner,  GRP_3_Runner,  GRP_4_Runner, ...

Each runner has the same content (except tag) for example:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"/features"},
        plugin = { "html:target/cukes"},
        glue = {"steps"},
        tags = "@GRP_1"
)
public class GRP_1_Runner{
}

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"/features"},
        plugin = { "html:target/cukes"},
        glue = {"steps"},
        tags = "@GRP_2"
)
public class GRP_2_Runner{
}

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"/features"},
        plugin = { "html:target/cukes"},
        glue = {"steps"},
        tags = "@GRP_3"
)
public class GRP_3_Runner{
}

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"/features"},
        plugin = { "html:target/cukes"},
        glue = {"steps"},
        tags = "@GRP_4"
)
public class GRP_4_Runner{
}
```

Each test case in group has a corresponding tag from the runner class
I use tags because i want to run each group of test cases separately.

Do I need to create a new runner for each tag in Cucumber? Is there any alternative to running each group of tests separately without having to create a new runner each time?

Comment: Why you created separate runner for each group?

Comment: @NandanA: because I want to run test cases from each group separately: Sometimes I want to run all test cases from GRP_1 User login (and none other), sometimes all test cases from GRP_2 Registration (and none other), etc..

Answer (score 2):

You can use logical operators to run tests with different combinations.

- You can use `or` operator to run all the `features`

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = {"/features"},
            plugin = { "html:target/cukes"},
            glue = {"steps"},
            tags = "@GRP_1 or @GRP_2 or @GRP_3 or @GRP_4"
    )
```

- You can use `and` operator to run the `features` which are having given `tags`

```
  @Grp_1 @Grp_2
  Test1_Userlogin.feature
  
  @GRP_2 
  Test1_Registration.feature
  
  @GRP_3
  Test1_Shipping.feature
```

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = {"/features"},
            plugin = { "html:target/cukes"},
            glue = {"steps"},
            tags = "@GRP_1 and @GRP_2"
    )
```

Now `Test1_Userlogin.feature` will be executed because it is the `feature` which is having both `@Grp_1` and `@Grp_2` tags

> Do I need to create a new runner for each tag in Cucumber? Is there
> any alternative to running each group of tests separately without
> having to create a new runner each time?

- If you want to have a single `Runner` class then you need to change the tags before each run based on criteria (like @Grp1, @Grp2 etc.)
- Even you can have multiple `Runner` classes to have different combination of tags instead of modifying the `Runner` class every time.
- You can run them from command line by changing `tag` name.

```
    mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Grp_1"
```

Comment: Hello @NandanA, a question if you have multiple runners with different tags and you go to use mvn command with the specified gs tag, Junit will replace the CucumberOptions tag for all runners with the one specified from maven. so in this case our test filtered from mvn will be executed X time where X depends on how many runners we have.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one,  **tags = {"@GRP_1, @GRP_2"}**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features={"src/test/java/Features/"},
        plugin  = {"json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json"},
        tags = {"@run1, @run2"},
        glue = "StepDefinitions"
)
public class RunTest {
}
```

Comment: This format is deprecated in latest cucumber version.